# Bind click function to different pictures

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I have 6 different pictures. I want to show a new div for each picture clicked.

At the moment, I have this:

```
<script>
$('a.links').click(function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var div_id = $('a.links').index($(this))
   $('.divs').hide().eq(div_id).show();
});
</script>
```

Which works for "a.links" - how can I bind the click function to my pictures? I need to edit the jquery to make this work:

```
<img src="HGBai.png" href="#id_of_div" id="link_1" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<img src="CHebb.png" href="#id_of_div2" id="link_2" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div2">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how come it is working for first a.links when you have `img` tag in your html code

Comment: That was a sample for a.links. Obviously, it does not work right now, because I don't get it how to bind the click function to my picture. Changing "a.links" to "img" does not work.

Comment: If you figured out, how to find all elements matching `a.links`, you will as well figure out how to find all images with a class-name of `.links`. The schema is the same. But on the other hand, this question smells like you copied the code from somewhere, and used it without understanding the code.

Comment: “Changing "a.links" to "img" does not work” What does “not work” mean in that context, because using `img` as selector would be one possible answer…

Comment: btw: `img` elements don't have an `href`-attribute;

Comment: Why didn't you leave the code as is (i.e. with <a> elements) and simply put the <img>s in the <a>s?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the click event to your elements class:

```
$('.links').click(function (e){
   //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
$('img.links').click(function(e) {
  var div_id = $(".links").index($(this))
  $('.divTable').hide().eq(div_id).show();
});
```

Since I can't find an element with the class `divs` then i replace it with `divTable` for this example

**DEMO**

```js
$('img.links').click(function(e) {
  var div_id = $(".links").index($(this))
  $('.divTable').hide().eq(div_id).show();
});
```

```css
.divTable{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="HGBai.png" href="#id_of_div" id="link_1" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<img src="CHebb.png" href="#id_of_div2" id="link_2" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div2">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">2</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set related div id in `data-div-id`attribute and read it inside click handler of image to show it and hide all other divs

**NOTE** : href is not relevant attribute for image tag but for anchor tag so don't use it

```js
$(function(){
  $('img.links').on('click', function(){
     var div = $(this).data('div-id'); // get div id
     $('.divTable').hide(); // hide all div
     $(div).show(); // show relevant div
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="HGBai.png" data-div-id="#id_of_div" id="link_1" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<img src="CHebb.png" data-div-id="#id_of_div2" id="link_2" class="links">

<div class="divTable" id="id_of_div2">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```